# Find match in series excluding substrings

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like a very simple task but for some reason, I am having a hard time finding the answer. I have a long list of keywords I want to find in a column and I only want the exact match and not its substring.

keywords:

```
import pandas as pd
match = str(['NE', 'NW'])
```

column:

```
tmp = pd.Series(['acne', 'abc', 'ne', 'this is ne', 'nw'])
```

My attempt:

```
tmp.str.contains(match, case=False)
```

Results:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
```

'Acne' I do not want it to return as True because 'ne' does not exist on its own. What can I do to make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the whole string, you have to use `^` -> (starts with) and `$` -> (ends with).

You have to use `|` -> (for or condition).

```
import pandas as pd
match = ['NE', 'NW']

m2 = []
for val in match:
    m2.append('^'+val+'$')

match = '|'.join(m2)

tmp = pd.Series(['acne', 'abc', 'ne', 'this is ne', 'nw'])
res = tmp.str.contains(match, case=False)

print(res)
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more question is let's say I have a lot of words in the match variable. How could I add ^ and $ to all the values without manually inputting it?

Comment: You can add a loop to achieve this. See the updated post

Answer (score 3):

You could use word boundary(\b) in regex:

```
import pandas as pd
match = '|'.join([r'\bNE\b',r'\bNW\b'])
print(match)
tmp = pd.Series(['acne', 'abc', 'ne', 'this is ne', 'nw'])


tmp.str.contains(match, case=False)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Value at index 3 is wrong. It should be False since "ne" exists only as a substring.

Comment: Nope. He asks for strings that lives on their own. The output produced here is correct

Comment: @TainToTain The output is as the poster requested. Otherwise he needs to update the question and be more specific. We know more once he accepts an answer :-)

Comment: Okay, it seems that this is what he wants. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `match()`, which matches the entire pattern, instead of `contains`.

[The documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html) for `pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains` explains:

> match
>
> analagous, but stricter, relying on re.match instead of re.search

```
import pandas as pd
match = str(['NE', 'NW'])

tmp = pd.Series(['acne', 'abc', 'ne', 'this is ne', 'nw'])

print(tmp.str.match(match, case=False))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, one problem is that 'this is ne' should be true.

Comment: @Xin Please update your question to make this part clear. You stated that you "only want the exact match and not its substring" and also upvoted another answer that matches the exact pattern.